# Why is this piece of code to returning false?

Tags: php

i have

```
<?php  if($transaction_status_code != 00)  { 
  //dosomething
 } else {
   //do something
  } ?>
```

but the above code return true when $transaction_status_code = Z1, please what could be the problem

Comment: Because it's doing a cast to an int. Wrap your `00` in quotes. to make it a string comparison.

Comment: @Jon Stirling You should write it as an answer

Comment: i think Jon Stirling suggestion seems to have work....

Comment: If you get answer then marked as an answer for future user's sake. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is comparison of two different data type values.

`Z1` is string type while `00` is integer type. So you need to convert it to string for correct comparison.Put `00` in quotes.

```
<?php  if($transaction_status_code != "00")  { 
  //dosomething
 } else {
   //do something
  } ?>
```

**Note:- According to the problem that you discussed in your question,you need to change `!=` to `==` .**

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple, you are doing a not equals. != an equals would be == therefore Z1 would be true and 00 would be false